# React Native skips in-between rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a problem related to how the react native decides to skip re-rendering altogether when I change a state in the component.

I have a drop-down menu which when one of its option is chosen, it will load the option of the next drop-down. In this case: country and city. All I currently want to do is to show 'Loading' text under the city drop-down when a country is chosen. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
onCountryChange(country) {
    this.setState({loadingCity: true});
    //looping country array here to get the list of city option
    this.setState({loadingCity: false});
}
render () {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Country</Text>
            <View>
                <Dropdown
                style={{ height: 20, width: 300}} values={this.state.country_name} 
                selected={0}  onChange={this.onCountryChange.bind(this)}/>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View>
            <Text>City</Text>
            { this.state.selectedCountry != '' ?
                <View>
                    <Dropdown
                    style={{ height: 20, width: 300}} values={this.state.city_name} 
                    selected={0}  onChange={this.onCityChange.bind(this)}/>
                </View>
            :
                <Text>Please pick a country first</Text>
            }
            { this.state.loadingCity?
                <View>
                    <View>
                        <Image
                            style={{height: 10, width: 10}}
                            source={require('./images/loading.gif')} />
                    </View>
                    <Text>Loading</Text>
                </View>
            :
                null
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```

I tried to remove the line of code `this.setState({loadingCountry: false})` and it actually shows the loading text. But apparently, react native skips the render related to loadingCountry altogether when I add the line of code back. Is there any way to force the loading to appear? I already tried using `this.forceUpdate()`, however it still does not work.

Update: this is what I've tried to do using Timer Mixin:

```
onCountryChange(country) {
    this.setState({loadingCity: true});
    //looping country array here to get the list of city option
    this.setTimeout(this.setState({loadingCity: false}),100000);
}
```

But for some reasons, the setTimeout did not actually wait for 100s to fire the `this.setState({loadingCity: false})` function.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setState({loadingCity: true})` then `setState({loadingCity: false})` in the same synchronous code block won't render. Even if it did, it would probably be a flash quicker than you'd see.

If you want the loading indicator to stay, don't set it false.

If you only want it visible for a few seconds, wrap the `setState({loadingCity: false})` in a setTimeout (though dont forget to use react-timer-mixin).

Comment: I want it actually to stay only from the moment it shows the text 'please pick a country first', until it changed to the dropdown. In what way can I achieve this?

Comment: Just remove the `this.setState({loadingCity: false})` call. That way any time loadingCity is true it will display. I assume you're loading the cities with a fetch request or something similar. When the cities are loaded, set loadingCity to false to hide the spinner.

Comment: I actually only looping the array I already have in the asyncstorage. That's what makes the process super speedy.

Comment: Ok the setTimeout isn't working, cause your calling the function immediately, modify 

`this.setTimeout(this.setState({loadingCity: false}),100000);`

to be

`this.setTimeout(() => this.setState({loadingCity: false}),100000);`